# Clan experience war didn't recieve

Tags: clash-of-clans

Why we didn't get the clan experience and we won the war? We are about to try to start another war but we aren't might do the same thing.

Comment: My Clan lost and we got XP which is how i was abler to confirm the Star % XP stacked. unless it's some glitch affecting certain clans the only other thing i can think of is if you started the war before the update (ie. entered preparation day)

Comment: When you had started the war did you see any XP indicator in top right section in war mode ? We started the war after the update and we did receive the XP.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that this was a bug which I believe was fixed in the latest update "Maintenance 27/02 - Update Bug Fixes"

http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/571648-Maintenance-27-02-Update-Bug-Fixes?p=3984206&viewfull=1#post3984206

> 1. Fixed some issues with Clan XP not being correctly rewarded at the end of wars;
> 2. Healer does not trigger the Skeleton Air Trap anymore (consistent behavior as with the Air Bomb and Seeking Air Mine);
> 3. Teslas are no longer visible in the village thumbnail in Player Profile;
> 4. "Accept" button on a player clan join request works now correctly (some players might have encountered situations where the "accept" button malfunctioned while only the "reject" worked correctly);
> 5. Fixed issues writing special characters/Kaomoji into chat/clan-player names/etc;
> 6. Fixed that some clans could not have been found in search due to special characters/Kaomoji being used in their name.
> 7. Dragon attack fire breath visual effect fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was a maintence problem because we didn't get it until about 6-7 hours after the war ended